# To Delete Records using query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm facing a scenario where I need to delete record from the table.

The Scenario is:
The first table has some date values and the second table contains only year-end(date) records alone. If the first table's values is not in second table i need to delete this record from the first table.

**The following are the date values in first table**

```
2009-06-30 00:00:00.000
2009-12-31 00:00:00.000
2011-11-30 00:00:00.000
2011-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

**The following are the date values in second table**

```
2005-12-31 00:00:00.000
2006-12-31 00:00:00.000
2007-12-31 00:00:00.000
2009-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Here in comparing both tables, the first table's date values('2011-12-31 00:00:00.000
') is not in the second table. Hence I need to delete this record alone in first table.

I'm using the following query but I'm not getting the needed result.

**Query used**

```
Select tmp.* from #temp tmp
Inner Join #temp1 tmp1
On tmp.Val_DT != tmp1.ye_dt
Where DATEPART(mm,tmp.Val_dt) = 12
```

**Note:**
The second table only contains the year-end date alone.

How to achieve this?

Comment: First table's `2009-06-30 00:00:00.000` and `2011-11-30 00:00:00.000` are also not in the second table. Why not delete them too?

Answer (score 0):

this should be simple enough

```
Delete from Table1 where Table1DateField not in (select Table2DateField from Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),5)
```

you can get a varchar string of that date i.e. `05-04-12` and you can compare your date as a varchar string in this format and delete records easily.